# Fin de método await dentro de un Task.Run c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynctask, async-await

existe alguna forma de capturar el fin del metodo await dentro de un  Task.Run,

**Por ejemplo**
Necesito saber en que momento termino de ejecutarse el metodo await , para realizar la siguiente operacion

```
private async Task DoWork2Async()
{
  var t=  Task.Run( () =>
    {
        var result=await metodoAsync();
    });
}
```

algo parecido a esto, capturar mediante eventos el estado

```
.then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: cuando utilizas       var result=await metodoAsync(); ya no es necesario crear una tarea, simplemente despues de  que finalice tu metodoAsync sigue con la proxima instruccion.

Comment: @MiguelZarate gracias por tu comentario, efectivamente ya no lo necesito, pero en el caso si lo fuera , como manejaría el evento concluido, esto es posible?

Comment: puedes declarar la tarea como lo hiciste al principio y agreagas continue with, int resultadoVentas = await Task.Run(() => Sumarventas())
            .ContinueWith(task => RestarGastos(task));